# Zend plugin's preDispatch can't see roles

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, acl

I try to use ACL in plugin's preDispatch method and it can't see roles and resources.

in bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoLoad() {
...

$acl=new Application_Model_LibraryAcl();
$auth=Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$fc= Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$fc->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_AccessCheck($acl, $auth));
...
}
```

in plugin's preDispatch:

```
$this->_acl = $acl;
$this->_auth=Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$identity = $this->_auth->getStorage()->read();
$role=$identity->role;
$resource = $request->getControllerName();
$action= $request->getActionName();
if($this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $action)){
...
}
```

And I get error 'role 'admin' not found' (this error is for all roles). No matter what I tried to do it doesn't work. I solve this problem by moving ACL code from Model to this plugin but I think it is not very good idea to keep ACL here. Other models and controllers can see ACL from Application_Model_LibraryAcl and it's roles and resources but plugin's preDispatch doesn't want to.

I use ZF 1.12.

EDIT. My Application_Model_LibraryAcl() is:

```
<?php
class Application_Model_LibraryAcl extends Zend_Acl {

    public function __construct(){




        //----------------------ADD ROLES HERE---------------------------------

        $acl = new Zend_Acl();
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'), 'guest');
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'user');


        //----------------------ADD RESOURCES HERE---------------------------------

        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('authentication'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index'));


        //----------------------ADD PERMITIONS HERE---------------------------------

        $acl->deny();

        $acl->allow('admin', NULL);
        $acl->allow('guest', 'authentication', array('login', 'registration', 'confirm', 'index' ));
        $acl->allow('guest', 'index', array('index' ));
        $acl->allow('user', 'index', array('index', 'confirm'));
        $acl->allow('user', 'authentication', array('logout' ));
        $acl->deny('user', 'authentication', array('login' ));


    }

}
```

I keep role of current user in Zend storage. This code works fine when I move all code from model to plugin without any changing. I have error on this string if I use model:

```
if($this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $action))
```

and no any errors when I use ACL as part of plugin.

Comment: What class is `$identity` and how does it load the roles? Or are these stored in the session?

Comment: Can you show code for `Application_Model_LibraryAcl`? After all, that's the component that needs to know about the roles.

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't get an error on first load, when `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()` returns `null`. In that case, a reference to `$identity->role` should give an error "attempting to access property on null object".

Comment: One thing to look at could be this: You pass `$auth` as a constructor param to the plugin, but in `preDispatch()` you seem to grab `$auth` directly as `Zend_Auth::getInstance()`. It's a singleton, so shouldn't matter, but it's odd enough to warrant a looking at it.

Comment: Also, you say that in `preDispatch()`, you have access to a var called `$acl`. Should be `$this>_acl`. Are you using the correct signature for the `preDispatch()` method in your plugin? Remember, the correct signature is `public function preDispatch($request)`. Constructor signature can be anything, but from the usage you have already posted, yours will be `__construct($acl, $auth)`. Maybe post code for the entire plugin?